# Hibernate LazyLoading initialization of List

Tags: sql, hibernate, lazy-loading

I've typical User and Comment-Models. One user has more comments.
On one usecase i want to get only a user from db, without comments.
I thought, as soon i tell "getComments()", so only in this moment, my List will initialized with
something like "select comment from Comment c where c.userId = 1" from Hibernate.
But my List of comments will be initialized everytime when i say findyById or "select user from User".

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
@ToString(exclude = {"comments") 
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Builder.Default
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
    
}
```

My Comment Model:

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Comment implements Serializable{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @Builder.Default
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private User user; }
```

UserRepository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
@Query("SELECT user FROM User user WHERE user.id =:id")
Optional<User> findUserById(@Param("id") long id); }
```

When i tell:

```
userRepository.findUserById(1);
```

So i see at first only one select-statment for user.
Few seconds later i see next statment for comment, but i did not tell "user.getComments()"
So how can i get User-Model without any Lazy-List's with related Object?

Comment: can you add the whole method that calls `userRepository.findUserById(1)` as well as the whole `User` class?

Comment: I've found out a problem, i've a User-DTO object, which maps a User-Object.
So at next line, i'am mapping my entity. While mapping new dto-object tries to fill out child-entity in the list, at retrieve it. So i execute lazy-init Lists with "getComment()"